# How to get memcached stats without nc?

Tags: bash, shell, automation, memcached

this is how I'm getting the stats now:
echo -e "stats\nquit" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211

I can't use expect as it's not part of a default installation.

Is there a way to get memcached stats without nc?

Comment: You care about "default installation" on which OS, precisely? (Not everyone has `/dev/tcp` compiled in by default... nor, for that matter, telnet)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question doesn't specify *why* you're looking for an alternative to netcat, so it's hard to to tell what you're looking for.  You could do it in `bash` like this:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/11211
echo -e "stats\nquit" >&3
cat <&3
```

You could do it using `telnet`:

```
(echo -e 'stats\nquit'; sleep 1) | telnet localhost 11211
```

The `sleep` is to precent `telnet` from exiting before receiving a response from `memcached`.

You could also write something simple in `python` or `perl` or some other high level scripting language.  Or brush up on your `c`.  There are lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

Another, possibly simpler way, is with the memcached-tool script. It came installed with my installation of memcached 1.4.5 via yum, but under apt and ubuntu I didn't get it. I found it here and put it on my system: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/memcached/memcached/master/scripts/memcached-tool

on the server, type the following to get memcached stats:
`memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 stats`

or the following to get slabs:
`memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211`

assuming your server is listening on port 11211 and IP 127.0.0.1 (set config options at /etc/sysconfic/memcached)

article: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-linux-install-memcached-caching-system-rpm/